# Unable to install libcurl4-gnutls-dev package in Cloudera VM

Tags: linux

sudo apt -get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev shows the attached error.

[image: terminal-screenshot]

Please provide a solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned command has an extra space. It should be `apt-get`. Try

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```